# iOS9 - NSURLSession fails to parse response but AlamoFire works

Tags: swift, ios9, alamofire, nsurlsession

I am trying to move away from `AlamoFire` to `NSURLSessions` and trying to make a `GET` request to an endpoint that returns a `JSON` (An array of dictionary).

Below is header from `Alamofire` code that is **successful**:

```
GET /Path/?lastrequest=2006-08-25T03:25:21Z HTTP/1.1
Host    one.domain.com
Cookie  connect.sid=s%3A8gUYZmxHWn9PJ95ZJF9P6FGrdrcPIueG.KcXee%2FT8VI1SeAaVvOwcHdOuCLydPvU%2BLiqlZHu2QfI
x-token $2a$10$Vif5iFua8/EdITuaibyO.ANoGm8EuNORBLjXVaxwSJ.a.1472443117
Accept  */*
User-Agent  MyApp/com.MyApp.test (1; OS Version 9.3 (Build 13E230))
Accept-Language en-US;q=1.0
Accept-Encoding gzip;q=1.0,compress;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
```

`AlamoFire` `Successful` response info:

```
Size    
Request Header  475 bytes
Response Header 173 bytes
Request -
Response    87.66 KB (89762 bytes)
Total   88.29 KB (90410 bytes)
Request Compression -
Response Compression    -

Response Code   200 OK
Protocol    HTTP/1.1
Method  GET
Kept Alive  Yes
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Client Address  /127.0.0.1
```

Now the header using `NSURLSession` that **fails**:

```
GET /Path/?lastrequest=2006-08-25T03:25:21Z HTTP/1.1
Host    one.domain.com
Accept  */*
Connection  keep-alive
x-token $2a$10$Vif5iFua8/EdITuaibyO.ANoGm8EuNORBLjXVaxwSJ.a.1472443117
Cookie  connect.sid=s%3ATRSrme3Q4yLchJu-3KanYLi8lKJgITbh.xO0uUEIFsWQ7McIyA36%2BgJi7aPWb9MYxSEn9nYKzUA8
Accept-Language en-US;q=1.0
Content-Length  2
Accept-Encoding gzip;q=1.0,compress;q=0.5
User-Agent  NetworkLayer/1 CFNetwork/758.3.15 Darwin/15.6.0
```

`NSURLSession` **Failure** response info:

```
Size    
Request Header  476 bytes
Response Header 173 bytes
Request -
Response    12.73 KB (13032 bytes)
Total   13.36 KB (13681 bytes)
Request Compression -
Response Compression    -
```

I do see extra fields in the `header` that not there with `AlamoFire`, but I don't know how to turn them off.

**NRURLSession** is also making 3-4 concurrent calls.

`NSURLSession` **failed** response:

```
Response:  Failed to parse data (org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1) 

Failure Client closed connection before receiving entire response
Response Code   200 OK
Protocol    HTTP/1.1
Method  GET
Kept Alive  No
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Client Address  /127.0.0.1
```

Here is the `header` that I configured in `NSURLSession`:

```
 var headers: [String: String]? {
            return ["x-token" : token!,
                    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip;q=1.0,compress;q=0.5",
                    "Accept-Language": "en-US;q=1.0"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it your endpoint, or a third-party's?  Could the server be blocking you based on, say, the user-agent?

Answer (score 0):

The reason Content-Length = 2 kept showing up in the header is because I was sending an empty string for the dictionary. When I sent a nil instead, it worked liked a charm.